# Weird jQuery behavior - slide()

Tags: jquery, css

if you go to this page and hit one of the left dropdowns - http://ryancoughlin.com/hp/index.php?c=about - it almost looks like it is glitching/bumping, once it gets to the bottom or rides back up top.

Is it possible to fix this? Or is this how it behaves in jQuery?

CODE:

```
$(".menu-header").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
}).next().hide();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your CSS, change

```
#left ul li{
    font-size:.7em;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

to

```
#left ul li{
    font-size:.7em;
    padding:2px 0 3px 0;
}
```

The issue is that your margins are collapsing with the margins of the `h2` at the beginning and end of the animation, but not during the animation, because `overflow` of the `ul` is not `visible`*, preventing the collapsing.  The lack of collapsing increases the effective size of the `ul`.

*[W3 on the box model and margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> Vertical margins of elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible' do not collapse with their in-flow children.

Comment: Hey, that seemed to do the trick. Why did that work? Margin problems>?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: If this is the answer to your problem, please mark it as so. :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with margin. Try animating {"margin": toggle}  at the same time and that should get rid of the bumping:

```
$(".menu-header").click(function() {
  $(this).next().animate({"margin": "toggle", "height": "toggle"});
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry! I am using toggle, check my code above, will that still work?

Comment: Hey Seb, i tried that and still the same thing, I will give those other answers above a shot. It seems like that should work, the code you posted.

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it might be to do with the margin and padding that you have set on the `h2` header link. If you inspect the page with firebug, and set `padding` and `margin` to 0 on the header, then the "bump" disappears. Also, a number of styles appear to be calculated next to the `ul` when it is shown or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem few days ago with a similar piece of code.

From what I've read, the problem is that you need to trigger "hasLayout" in all browsers. Of course, is not a real `hasLayout` thing, but you need to do one of these:

- Float elements. Both titles and lists and add clear:left for both. this should do the trick;
- Set width/height for `UL` elements (hidden stuff);
- add `position:relative` for `UL` elements

Usually, those should do the trick ;)