# slideToggle height is "jumping"

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

My jQuery `slideToggle()` experiment

Can anybody tell me why my boxes "jump" when i open them? The first half they slide, the rest they "jump"??

*Thanks,*
Johannes

Answer (score 25):

What's helping for me is

```
overflow: hidden
```

to the  that toggle...

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` was the magic sauce for me. I tried`position: relative;` and `min-height: 0;`, but neither worked.

Answer (score 24):

Its a simple fix. Add this CSS rule to your stylesheet (*Tested in Firebug to work, and from my past experience with this problem, this is the fix*):

```
ol.message_list { position: relative }
```

It is a CSS bug, not a jQuery bug per se.

Comment: I had the same problem, and tried this fix, but it didn't work for me so I had to give up and take a different approach (right before the slide, make the sliding-in portion visible with opacity 0, move the container up that much, then just slide it back down that way).

Comment: Just had this problem, thanks to Google & Stack Overflow this solution worked for me too. To abstract it, the container of the element that slides needed `position:relative`.

Comment: In my case both the element to be toggled and its parent needed the  position:relative-fix.

Answer (score 11):

The quickest fix in your case:

```
.message_container { width: 361px; }
```

I'm not sure exactly why, but not giving the container a fixed width when containing a `<p>` causes issues, give it one and the jumpyness goes away.

Comment: This also seems to be true for other text-oriented elements, such as `<label>`.

Answer (score 6):

css padding and jquery slideToggle doesn't work well together. Try to box out padding.

Answer (score 5):

I found this problem in many occasions in which I was animating just the height with `slideToggle` but not the margin/padding.

So, something like this might solve it:

```
$("#thediv").slideToggle().animate({"margin-bottom": "toggle"});
```

Answer (score 4):

If set, the `min-height` property can also trigger such a glitch. In this case you need to reset it :

```
.toggle-container {
position: relative;
min-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally I think that the easiest to use solution is to add custom function to jQuery with animate padding/margin-top/bottom too.

```
//this function is to avoid slideToggle jQuery jump bug.
$.fn.slideShow = function(time,easing) { return $(this).animate({height:'show','margin-top':'show','margin-bottom':'show','padding-top':'show','padding-bottom':'show',opacity:1},time,easing); }
$.fn.slideHide = function(time,easing) {return $(this).animate({height:'hide','margin-top':'hide','margin-bottom':'hide','padding-top':'hide','padding-bottom':'hide',opacity:0},time,easing);  }
```

And useage example:

```
$(this).slideShow(320,'easeOutQuart');
$(this).slideHide(320,'easeOutQuart');
```

My example animated opacity toggle tu, you can modify it as you need.

Answer (score 2):

I find the easiest fix is usually to remove the padding from the element that slides, and add padding to an element **inside** the sliding element.

In this example the div with the attribute of `data-role="content"` is the one that slides, and the padding is applied to `tab-example__content`

```
<div data-role="content" class="tab-example__content">
    ...
</div>
```

To fix the 'jerky' sliding I added a new div inside the sliding element and moved the class/padding to that, like so:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="tab-example__content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

It's now nice and smooth

Answer (score 0):

I have found yet another thing that affects it. Removing `min-height` from the CSS of that element fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

if the toggled box hasn't height by default, you need to add it, for auto height add this:

```
.toggle-container {
 height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found setting a width on the toggled container resolved the issue for me

```
.toggle-container { 
   width: 100%; }
}
```

I read slideToggle relies on a starting width and height to function correctly so depending on your page you may need to set width or height to get the behavior you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

In my past situation I had the same problem, and the problem was that I had the `transition: all 350ms;` declaration in my CSS which was conflicting with `.slideToggle`. Removing that fixed it for me, so look up for transitions in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue, but what fixed it for me was that I had previously used CSS to "animate" it, so I had a `transition` effect on the element. Removing it fixed it for me.