# Input loses placeholder and some styles after .slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, html

When I call the `.slideToggle()` method of jQuery 1.7.2, the input element lose its placeholder and its position is broken. It's gone to the top of the screen.

The CSS:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#second").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="first" placeholder="first" />
<input type="text" id="second" placeholder="second" style="display: none;" />
<button id="go">Go</button>
```

When I try to inspect this element in Google Chrome the placeholder goes back and styles are normalized.

Why does this happen?

Comment: It works fine in Safari 5.1.7 on Lion, which version of chrome/OS are you using? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: chrome 19 / win7 64bit but on ff 11 / win7 64 bit it works fine

Comment: maybe I should use smth. like this https://github.com/eymengunay/jquery-placeholder to fix the problem for now. But it still interesting for me - what fires this bug.

Comment: Interesting, it appears in Chrome for me as well. Sorry I couldn't find a solution. It seems like it might be related to the jumpiness bug of `slideToggle()` though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335461/jquery-slide-is-jumpy  My suggestion would be to use other jQuery method instead to achieve the same effect.