# PlaceHolder of input not shown in slide jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown

I have a button :

```
<a  data-role="button" data-transition="none"
data-theme="b" onclick="ShowInput();" data-icon="forward" data-iconpos="left">
</a>
```

By clicking on the button, the input slide down:

```
function ShowInput() {
    $('#IdIn').slideDown("slow");
}
```

My input:

```
<input placeholder="xxx" name="NameIn" id="IdIn" value="" type="text">
```

The slidedown works, but do not see the placeholder 'xxx' of the input

why?

Comment: In the script part there are extra brackets and semi-colon at the end.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? `placeholder` is [not supported everywhere](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder).

Comment: Brackets are just wrong here, I corrected....

Comment: The placeholder **work** without slide, so it's not a browser problem

Comment: You are right, there is a strange problem. Here is a fiddle which explain the problem you can add to your question : http://jsfiddle.net/6AB2d/

Comment: Works in firefox for me, but not Chrome

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom : looks like a browser issue. It works fine with firefox and opera.

Comment: It works for me in the fiddle ..

Comment: Yes, works in firefox and Chrome not work

Comment: But why without slide the placeholder work also in Chrome ?

Comment: setting a min-height for the input seems to make it preserve the placeholder value in chrome, but the animation becomes buggy.

Comment: It does not work with min-height

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input loses placeholder and some styles after .slideToggle()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771453/input-loses-placeholder-and-some-styles-after-slidetoggle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the placeholder disappears if the input element is not big enough to contain it. And it doesn’t reappear if you should change the height later, and this is what is happening when you use `slideDown()`.

I’m not sure if this is a chrome-specific bug, or if the behaviour is expected. However, it seems to work if you redraw the element by removing the style attribute when the animation is complete: http://jsfiddle.net/QYp9Y/

```
$('#IdIn').slideDown("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a container to hold input element and then show/hide container instead of input.

```
<div id="IdContainer">
<input placeholder="xxx" name="NameIn" id="IdIn" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

Then in javascript,

```
function ShowInput() {
    $('#IdContainer').slideDown("slow");
}
```