# Div slideUp and slideDown animation choppy with inline-block display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

My div with an "addition" class is not sliding smoothly, but rather choppy and jumpy.

Everything goes smoothly when I set the slide down div to block display, but I need the div to display **inline-block** after sliding down.

I have tried some possible solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335461/jquery-slide-is-jumpy) without any luck.

Here is a [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFkP8/).

*Note: I want to keep the HTML structure as is. I have simplified the code for demonstration purposes.*

**HTML**

```
<div class="input">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <div>
        <div class="addition">Input addition</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input">
    <label>Rest</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.addition {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {    
    $('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
        $(this).closest('div').find('.addition')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast').css('display', 'inline-block');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by animating the parent div instead.

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $(this).siblings('div')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
})
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rFkP8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rFkP8/4/

Try the following code, it is working as per your requirements

```
  $(function() {    
    $('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
        $(this).closest('div').find('.addition')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp'](100)('stable').css('display', 'inline-block');
    })
});
```

If you want to slow down animation just increase the time as per your likings :)

Comment: This does not set the display property to inline-block, but block.

Comment: @DownVoters Instead of coming here and down voting, can't you help him. Wouldn't it be nice if you come here to help and not just downvote :/